# Resize Tkinter Listbox widget when window resizes

Tags: python, listbox, resize, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter, and I've got a `Listbox` widget that I'd like to automatically-resize when changing the main window's size.

Essentially I would like to have a fluid height/width Listbox. If someone can point me to some documentation or provide a bit a code / insight, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 14):

You want to read up on the geometry managers [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) and [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm), which lets you place widgets in a window and specify whether they grow and shrink or not. There's a third geometry manager, [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm), but it's not used very often.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical")
lb = tk.Listbox(root, width=50, height=20, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=lb.yview)

scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
lb.pack(side="left",fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(0,100):
    lb.insert("end", "item #%s" % i)

root.mainloop()
```

If you wish to use `grid` instead of `pack`, remove the two lines that call `pack` and replace them with these four lines:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
lb.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

Note that with grid you have to take the extra step to configure the `weight` for the row and column that contains the listbox, otherwise tkinter won't allocate any extra space to the widget.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I'm still a little fizzy as to the advantages of pack vs grid and need to spend some time with the existing documentation.

Comment: Grid is useful if you need to lay things out in a grid, pack is a bit more useful for putting widgets in a horizontal or vertical arrangement (though it is a bit more complicated than that since many types of layouts can be achieved with either)

Comment: @BryanOakley I know this post is a bit old, but your example shows how to expand the listbox when using the `pack` geometry manager. Since the `grid` geometry manager does not accept the option `expand`, could you provide a simple example of making the listbox expandable when using the `grid` geometry manager?

Comment: @Engineer_Chris: sure, I've added an example using `grid`.

Answer (score 3):

The two main ways to allow a listbox to stretch when the window is resized are using the **.pack()** or **.grid()** methods.

> SPECS:
>
> Windows 7, Python 3.8.1, tkinter version: 8.6

## .pack()

I found the easiest way to do this is by using the `.pack()` method, and utilizing the `fill=` & `expand=True` options.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()                                              #Creates the main window

listbox=tk.Listbox(root)                                  #Create a listbox widget

listbox.pack(padx=10,pady=10,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)    #fill=tk.BOTH, stretch vertically and horizontally
                                                          #fill=tk.Y, stretch vertically
                                                          #fill=tk.X, stretch horizontally
```

If your listbox is placed in a **frame**, the frame will also need to use the `fill=` & `expand=True` options.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

frame1=tk.Frame(root)
frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

listbox=tk.Listbox(frame1)
listbox.pack(padx=10,pady=10,fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)
```

---

## .grid()

The alternative technique is to use the `.grid()` method and utilize the`sticky=` option. In addition, you will need to configure the *row* and *column* that the listbox resides in.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()  #create window
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)    #confiugures column 0 to stretch with a scaler of 1.
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)       #confiugures row 0 to stretch with a scaler of 1.

listbox=tk.Listbox(root)
listbox.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky='nsew')
```

The `sticky` option causes the listbox to *stick* to the "North" (Top), "South" (Bottom), "East" (Right), and "West" (Left) sides of the cell as it is stretched.

If your listbox is placed within a **frame**, you will need to configure the *column* and *row* that the **frame** is in, along with configure the *column* and *row* that the **listbox** is in.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()               #create window
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)  
root.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

frame1=tk.Frame(root)
frame1.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky='nsew')
frame1.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame1.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)

listbox=tk.Listbox(frame1)
listbox.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky='nsew')
```

---

## .pack() & .grid()

Now there is one other technique, but some people frown on it. The third technique is to utilize the `.pack()` method and `.grid()` method in the same script. You can mix different geometry management method in the same script as long as only a one management type is used per container. You can see an example of this below.

```
import tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()               #create window

frame1=tk.Frame(root)                                #container: root
frame1.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=True)                               
frame1.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame1.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
frame1.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)

listbox=tk.Listbox(frame1)                            #container: frame1
listbox.grid(row=0,rowspan=2,column=0,padx=5,pady=5,sticky='nsew') 

btn1=tk.Button(frame1,text='Demo1')                   #container: frame1        
btn1.grid(row=0,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)                          

btn2=tk.Button(frame1,text='Demo2')                   #container: frame1     
btn2.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=5, pady=5)                          

frame2=tk.Frame(root)                                 #container: root 
frame2.pack()

btn3=tk.Button(frame2,text='Demo3')                   #container: frame2
btn3.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

You can see above that the frames used `.pack()` while the listbox and buttons used `.grid()`. This was possible because the frames resided within the *root* container, while the listbox and buttons resided within their respective frames.

---

To check you tkinter version use:

```
import tkinter as tk
print(tk.TkVersion)
```

If you would like to learn about the differences between **fill** and **expand**, please see the following link.
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm