# Resize Tkinter listbox when window resizes with Grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a Tkinter application using the Grid geometry manager (It's my first time using Grid, and I love it! :D) that contains a scrolling listbox that displays options whenever a user selects an option.

It's working well, but the window is small and ugly. When I maximize it, everything else resizes fine (thanks to columnconfigure) but the listbox stays the same height. Is there a simple way to fix this?

(I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318103/python-tkinter-resize-listbox-widget-when-window-resizes) but it's for Pack, not Grid)

Thanks in advance.

Code sample because one was asked for:

```
self.tasklist = Listbox(self.frame, exportselection=0)
self.tasklist.grid(row=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)
yscroll = Scrollbar(self.frame, command=self.tasklist.yview, orient=VERTICAL)
yscroll.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=N+S)
```

Comment: Can we see a code sample, please?

Comment: @JoelCornett Okay, I added one

Comment: Sweet. Is the frame also `sticky`ed to it's parent window?

Comment: @JoelCornett Actually, `self.frame` is the `root` that was passed to the class. Should it be an actual frame and not the window?

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing more of your code it's impossible to say. Most likely your listbox is expanding properly, but your `self.frame` is not. Though, I don't see you giving any weight to the row and column that the listbox is in, so that could be a factor.

An easy way to debug this is to give `self.frame` a garish color that will stick out (red, bright green, etc). Then it will be easy to see if the listbox is properly resizing inside the frame, and if the frame is properly resizing inside its parent.